# Autolayout reduce height of certain views

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have the following view:
[image]

For an iPhone 4-sized screen, I'd like to keep the grey top section and green lower button the same size, anchored to the top and bottom respectively.  The grid of buttons in the middle should each reduce in size to fit the new display.

Since the view size is 88px smaller (548 - 460 = 88), and there are 4 rows of buttons, I would programatically reduce each one by 22px and move it into place.

But I'd like to do it through autolayout if this is possible.

How do I specify a constraint to keep the distance from the top and bottom THE SAME, and reduce the height of the view only?

I've anchoring them all against the top and bottom, but this just results in this:

[image]

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can constrain it to the top and bottom and just use a constant other than zero, but why not just constrain the view with the buttons to the bottom of the upper gray area, and the top of the green area, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with auto layout. Basically, you should anchor the gray header and call button footer to the top and bottom of the superview (respectively), and anchor each button to its neighbor. Then specify that each button should have the same height as the first.

Here's the visual format language for the constraints (which I think is a little clearer than trying to explain the constraints). `headerView` is the gray bar at the top, `footerView` is the view containing your green button, and the buttons are named appropriately.

```
V:|-[headerView]-0-[buttonOne]-0-[buttonFour(==buttonOne)]-0-[buttonSeven(==buttonOne)]-[buttonPlus(==buttonOne@800)]-0-[footerView]-|
```

Note that the priority is lower on `buttonPlus`'s height constraint. This is because the space between your header and footer views may not divide evenly among the buttons. Setting the priority lower than "required" (priority == 1000) allows the plus button to be slightly shorter or taller than the one button, but auto layout will still try to get it as close as possible.

The horizontal sizing is created similarly to the vertical sizing. Note that here, `buttonTwo` is allowed to be a slightly different size than others, in case the horizontal space doesn't divide evenly.

```
H:|-0-[buttonOne]-0-[buttonTwo(==buttonOne@800)]-0-[buttonThree(==buttonOne)]-0-|
```

Calculations where one view's height/width is equal to another's are expensive, and may require several passes. It's best to set the above constraints only on the first column of buttons, then constrain the other columns so that the top and bottom of each button is aligned to the first button in its row. You can do this by passing `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop|NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom` as the options parameter when creating the horizontal constraints for each row, and `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft| NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight` when creating the vertical constraints.

Edit: This is still possible to do with IB.

Comment: Austin - thank you so much! I really appreciate your efforts.  I spent about an hour and half plugging in all the constraints, testing it, realising there was something wrong, deleteing them and trying again.  I decided that for maintainability its probably best if I have two views and show the relevant view depending on the screen size.  I very much appreciate your efforts though!  DUNCAN